# select input within a div by name

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I need to update the value of some input fields of a form, using values from a second (dynamically generated) div.

Here’s the code

```
$("#second_update_form_data :input").each(function(index) {

//find all input fields in the second div
                var FieldName = $(this).attr("name");
                var FieldValue = $(this).val();

  //try to get the corresponding field from the original form to change it
                var Selector = "#TT_CartForm__form input[name=" + FieldName + "]";
                var OriginalFiled = $(Selector);
```

This does not work, but I’m not sure why. I could add an id to the original input fields and use that to select them, but I’d prefer to understand what’s wrong and use the correct selector.

Thanks in advance,
kind regards

EDIT:
I’m sorry, I realize I didn’t specified which part doesn’t work.
It is the last line, when I try to select using Selector, so it’s this last one that seems to be wrong

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Have you closed your each function?

Comment: Are there any errors coming up? Also a random side note, but do not use `Uppercase` for variables unless they are Classes / instsantiable objects n such.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the naming conventions. Yes, the each function is closed, the error is on the line var OriginalFiled = $(Selector); if I remove or comment that it works till the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> UPdated based on your update

```
var OriginalFiled = $('#TT_CartForm__form input[name="' + FieldName + '"]');
```

Try changing your quotations around to ensure string vaiable read. something else to keep in mind, IE7 and IE8 support attribute selectors only if a !DOCTYPE is specified. and in IE6- they dont work ata all

Also double check your element ID name, I notice it has two areas that are underscore and one area has 2 underscores. Make sure the div holding your input has that exact same id value

Comment: Ahah, pretty simple but could‘t see at all! :D Thank you very much, for the further info as well.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly faster selector:

```
$('#second_update_form_data').find('input').each(function(index) {

    //find all input fields in the second div
    var fieldName     = $(this).attr('name'),
        fieldValue    = $(this).val(),

    //try to get the corresponding field from the original form to change it
        selector      = 'TT_CartForm__form input[name=' + fieldName + ']',
        originalFiled = $(selector);
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
$("#second_update_form_data :input")
```

to

```
$("#second_update_form_data input")
```

Comment: This wouldn't fix the issue, `:input` is deprecated jQuery, same as doing `input`, just slower.

Comment: Didn't know about this. Incase anyone else finds this: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9400 has more details

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the dynamically generated divs. You need to use .on()

[jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: How do you mean? I don’t need to attach a handler, I need to select an existing field.